# Does PBRUN disable SUDO functionality?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo

Does PBRUN disable SUDO? Can they be run in parallel until proven?

Comment: This is a question you need to ask your vendor, _Beyond Trust_. I am pretty sure they can coexist, but it might also be configured in such a way to disable other elevated privilege mechanisms, such as su, sudo, etc.

Answer (score 1):

PBRUN and SUDO can be run in parallel.  There is nothing inherent in PBRUN that will cause SUDO to failor disable it.  However, there are mechanism that can be configured within a Powerbroker policy that would ultimately prevent the use of SUDO if it existed on a system.  You would have to explicitly configure that.

I do not believe this is something you will find in documentation anywhere, but through my experience with Powerbroker, I believe this to be the case.